# Alternating series, Find General term.

Tags: calculus, sequences-and-series

Recently I was thinking about this series, something that alternates in gaps of 2. What is a possible formula for the $n$th term of this series, if there is one?

I am referring to the sequence shown below:
$$-1, -1, 1, 1, -1, -1, 1, 1, -1, -1....$$

Comment: Are you trying to find a formula for $a_n$ where $a_n$ is the $n$th term in this sequence?

Comment: Yes. Thats what I am trying to do.

Comment: https://oeis.org/A087960 essentially

Answer (score 0):

$a_n=(-1)^{\frac {n(n+1)} 2}$ is the formula you are looking for.

Comment: How will you expand this in series that alternates in gaps of 3? Like $$-1, -1, -1, 1, 1, 1, -1, -1, -1,...$$

Comment: Any integer $n$ can be written as $3m+r$ with $0\leq r <3$. Take $a_n=(-1)^{m+1}$. @user71072

Comment: For integer $n=3$, $m=1$, which means is $a_3=1$.@Kavi

Comment: @user71072 Sorry. I should have written $n-1$ as $3m+r$.

Comment: @user71072 If you want an explicit formula, write $$a_n = (-1)^{\lfloor \frac{n}{3} \rfloor+1}$$